# f#: initialize array of array

Tags: f#

in the following code, does array of array `A = B`?

```
let A =  Array.init  3 (fun _ -> Array.init 2 (fun _ -> 0))
let defaultCreate n defaultValue = Array.init n (fun _ -> defaultValue)
let B = defaultCreate 3 (defaultCreate 2 0)
```

if I assign values to `A and B`, they are different ,what happened? thanks.

```
 for i = 0 to 2 do
     for j = 0 to 1 do
            A.[i].[j] <-i + j
            B.[i].[j] <-i + j
 printfn "%A vs %A" A  B

A = [|[|0; 1|]; [|1; 2|]; [|2; 3|]|] and B = [|[|2; 3|]; [|2; 3|]; [|2; 3|]|]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same.

Arrays are reference types, and are stored on the heap. When you create an array with another array as the default value, you are storing references to the same array, over and over again.

Numbers are another thing. They are immutable, and are stored by value, on the stack. So you can't change the value of `1` to anything other than `1`.

To create an "jagged" array, you need to call `Array.init` from inside the initializer to the first `Array.init` call, to create new arrays for each slot.

Also; You could use `Array.create` if you do want to have the same value in every slot. Be careful about reference types though.

```
let A = Array.init 3 (fun _ -> Array.create 2 0)
```

Comment: `ValueType`s like `System.Int32` will not always be "stored on the stack".

Comment: @Stephen - True. It could be boxed or wrapped in a reference type. But storing it on the stack is what sets it apart from reference types.

Comment: Value *semantics* is what sets value types apart from reference types. The fact that they're usually stored on the stack is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

```
let B = defaultCreate 3 (defaultCreate 2 0)
```

You create an array and then you use this array as values for each cell.
It's as if you did something like this:

```
let a = [|1; 2; 3; 4|]
let b = [|a; a; a; a|]
```

The same array `a` is used for every cell (think pointer to `a` is you're used to C). Thus, modifying `b.[0].[1]` will change every `a.[1]`.

In my sample:

```
> b.[0].[1] <- 10;;
val it : unit = ()

> b;;
[|[|1; 10; 3; 4|]; [|1; 10; 3; 4|]; [|1; 10; 3; 4|]; [|1; 10; 3; 4|]|]
```

The same thing happens with your code.